# How to reuse validator class in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am currently writing custom validator for Spring Boot app and its idea is mainly to do some validations depending on other validations. For example, I want one field to be @NotNull if some other field is null, but the idea is to make it more generic, so that this conditional validations can be changed.
For this purpose I tried to use validation classes from annotations, that already exist, like @NotNull or @Size, but turned out they don't have them:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface NotNull {
}
```

What do these braces after validatedBy mean? How can I get the Validator that this interface uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your own constraint annotation, you should define your validator in `@Constraint` using `validatedBy` attribute.

Validators for built-in constraint-annotations are registred in [`ConstraintHelper`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/7.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/core/ConstraintHelper.html) class in its constructor, therefore the curly brackets are empty. For example, validator registration for `@NotNull` annotation in `ConstraintHelper` constructor looks so:

`putConstraint( tmpConstraints, NotNull.class, NotNullValidator.class );`

If you want to see built-in implementations of `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator`, go to `org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators` package. Or if you are using Intellij Idea:

> Right click on declaration of `ConstraintValidator` -> Go To -> Implementation(s)

So, to reuse this validators you can create your custom annotation and put built-in annotations on it:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface NotNullAndNotEmpty {
    String message() default "some message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload> [] payload() default {};
}
```

, or you can initialize some built-in validator in your custom validator and call its `isValid()` method in your `isValid()` method.